# Google App Engine: Datastore Query in which the WHERE clause points to a Reference Property

Tags: google-app-engine

In my datastore I have an entity `Book` that has reference to `Owner` that has reference to `ContactInfo` which has a property `zipcode` on it. I want to query for all books within a certain zipcode. How can I do this? I understand I can't write a query where I can do:

```
q = db.Query(Book).filter('owner.contact_info.zipcode =', 12345)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of thing you *cannot* do with the App Engine datastore. It is not a relational database, and you cannot query it as one. One of the things this implies is that it does not support JOINs, and you cannot do queries across entity types.

Because of this, it is usually not a good idea to follow the full normalized form in creating your data models. Unless you have a very good reason for keeping them separate, ContactInfo should almost certainly be merged with Owner. You might also want to define a repeated ReferenceProperty on Owner that records `books_owned`: then you can do a simple query and some gets to get all the books:

```
owners = db.Query(Owner).filter('zipcode', 12345)
books = []
for owner in owners:
    book_ids.extend(owner.books_owned)
books = db.get(book_ids)
```

**Edit** the field would look like this:

```
class Owner(db.Model):
    ...
    books_owned = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

If you update the schema, nothing happens to the existing entities: you will need to go through them (perhaps using the remote API) and update them to add the new data. Note though that you can just set the properties directly, there's no database migration to be done.

Comment: thanks. can you explain the bit on repeated ReferenceProperty on Owner that records books_owned?

Comment: also what happens to the existing entities in the datastore if I make schema changes as you suggest?

Comment: adding this comment for completeness. I think there is no need for books_owned property on Owner. As explained in the One to Many section of https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling, since Book has a ReferenceProperty to Owner, an Owner can backreference all the books owned by it.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But note that will be one datastore query for every Owner, whereas my proposal is one single get for the whole thing.

Comment: One more question. I want to get books sorted by date_created in descending order. How can that be done? Assume Book class has a date_created property on it.

Answer (score 0):

If contact info is a separate model, you will first need to find all `ContactInfo` entities with `zipcode == 12345`, then find all of the `Owner` entities that reference those `ContactInfo` entities, then find all the `Book` entities that reference those `Owner` entities.

If you're still able to change your model definitions at all, it would probably be wise to denormalize at least `ContactInfo` in the `Owner` model, and possibly also the `Owner` inside each `Book`.